# Adding View into scroll view

Tags: iphone, ios

I have created one scroll view and on the scroll view, i am adding two alternate custom UIView  s

```
@interface FirstView : UIView
@interface SecondView : UIView
```

my array is

```
 NSMutableArray *classArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:firstView, secondView, firstView, secondView,  nil];
```

i am adding views on scroll view in following manner

```
for ( i = 0 ; i< 5; i++) 
{

    UIView *userView = [classArray objectAtIndex:i];
    CGRect rect;
    rect.size.height = KVIEWHGT;
    float userViewWidth = userView.frame.size.width;
    rect.size.width = userViewWidth;
    userView.frame = rect;
    [scrollView addSubview:userView];
    [userView release];

}

UIView *userView = nil;
NSArray *userSubViews = [scrollView subviews];
CGFloat x = 0;
float userViewWidth = 0.0f;
for (userView in userSubViews) {
    if ([userView isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]){
        CGRect frame = userView.frame;
        frame.origin = CGPointMake(x, 0);
        userView.frame = frame;
        userViewWidth = userView.frame.size.width;
        x += userViewWidth + 10;
    }
}

[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(x, scrollView.frame.size.height)];
```

I am getting output as only two custom views on scroll view but i want there should be 5 custom view on the scroll views

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding firstView ,secondView multiple time in the array, even though you add it multiple time it refers to the same instance

```
 NSMutableArray *classArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:firstView, secondView, firstView, secondView,  nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

A UIView can only have one parent view. You are using the same UIView instance multiple times. If you add a UIView to another, it is removed from the one it is currently attached to.

Read UIView Class Reference, addSubview:

> Views can have only one superview. If view already has a superview and that view is not the receiver, this method removes the previous superview before making the receiver its new superview.

Comment: I am adding all UIView on the UIScrollView

Comment: I know, but looking at your array "[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:firstView, secondView, firstView, secondView,  nil];" you are using the same instances multiple times. You need to create unique UIView instances for each UIView on the screen, they can be of the same type/class. This means *view1 = [FirstView alloc] init], *view2 = [[FirstView alloc] init], *view3 = [[SecondView alloc] init], *view4 = [[SecondView alloc] init].... etc

Answer (score 0):

even if it works, you would have duplicated views in your scrollview. you have to create x instances of you views and add them to your scrollview.

thats kind of creepy code anyway.

1.

```
UIView *userView = [classArray objectAtIndex:i];
[userView release];
```

you dont have to release this, because its not yours!

2: why iterating twice over the views? makes no sense, better

```
NSMutableArray* myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: firstView,secView,thirdView,fourthView]; 

for (UIView* view in myArray)
{ 
     //set the Frame and add it the the ScrollView
}
```